# PySpark/DataBricks: How to read parquet files using 'file:///' and not 'dbfs'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to use `petastorm` in a different manner which requires that I tell it where my parquet files are stored through one of the following:

`hdfs://some_hdfs_cluster/user/yevgeni/parquet8`, or `file:///tmp/mydataset`, or `s3://bucket/mydataset`, or `gs://bucket/mydataset`. Since I am on DataBricks and given other constraints, my option is to use the `file:///` option.

However, I am at a loss as to how specify the location of my parquet files. I continually get rejected saying that `Path does not exist:`

#### Here is what I am doing:

```
# save spark df to parquet
dbutils.fs.rm('dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train.parquet', recurse=True)
assembled_train.write.parquet('dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train')
```

```
# look at files
display(dbutils.fs.ls('mnt/team01/assembled_train/'))
```

```
# results
path    name    size
dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train/_SUCCESS   _SUCCESS    0
dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train/_committed_2150262571233317067 _committed_2150262571233317067  856
dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train/_started_2150262571233317067   _started_2150262571233317067    0
dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train/part-00000-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035357-1-c000.snappy.parquet  part-00000-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035357-1-c000.snappy.parquet   578991
dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train/part-00001-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035358-1-c000.snappy.parquet  part-00001-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035358-1-c000.snappy.parquet   579640
dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train/part-00002-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035359-1-c000.snappy.parquet  part-00002-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035359-1-c000.snappy.parquet   580675
dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train/part-00003-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035360-1-c000.snappy.parquet  part-00003-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035360-1-c000.snappy.parquet   579483
dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train/part-00004-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035361-1-c000.snappy.parquet  part-00004-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035361-1-c000.snappy.parquet   578807
dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train/part-00005-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035362-1-c000.snappy.parquet  part-00005-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035362-1-c000.snappy.parquet   580942
dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train/part-00006-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035363-1-c000.snappy.parquet  part-00006-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035363-1-c000.snappy.parquet   579202
dbfs:/mnt/team01/assembled_train/part-00007-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035364-1-c000.snappy.parquet  part-00007-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035364-1-c000.snappy.parquet   579810
```

While testing with a basic dataframe load from the file structure, like so:

````
df1 = spark.read.option("header", "true").parquet('file:///mnt/team01/assembled_train/part-00000-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035357-1-c000.snappy.parquet')```
````

I get file does not exist.

Comment: just wondering what would happen if you remove 'file://' or use 'dbfs:/'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify the path as it is, no need for 'file:///':

```
df1 = spark.read.option("header", "true").parquet('/mnt/team01/assembled_train/part-00000-tid-2150262571233317067-79e6b077-3770-47a9-9fec-155a412768f1-1035357-1-c000.snappy.parquet')
```

If this doesn't work, try the methods in https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/load-data/petastorm.html#configure-cache-directory

Comment: Thanks, that does work for that purpose but Petastorm still does not like it. The link you gave me, in addition to your comment, does help me get a bit further and I appreciate it greatly!